# How can I create a materialized view in Cassandra using spring-data?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, materialized-views

Is it possible to create Materialized Views in Cassandra using spring-data? Or any other way in that kind of setup? I don't want to execute queries with cqlsh manually.